# undefined method "arel_table" for Images:Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to user has_many :through association following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) docs.

I have 3 models

Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :image_posts
  has_many    :images, :through => :image_posts

end
```

Image

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many    :image_posts

  has_many    :posts, :through => :image_posts

end
```

and ImagePost

```
class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :images
  belongs_to :posts
end
```

And when I try to:

```
post = Post.last
post.images
```

I receive `"undefined method "arel_table" for Images:Module"` error.

What is `arel_table` and how to fix this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a problem while defining the belongs_to association. It should always singular like

```
class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of a helper.

```
undefined method `arel_table' for Talent:Module
```

My module was `talent/profile/header_helper.rb`

```
module Talent
  module Profile
    module HeaderHelper
      def display_experience(talent)
        talent.years_of_experience.present?  ? "#{talent.years_of_experience} #{t('.experience_years')}" : default_message
      end

      def default_message
        "No especificado"
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

This helper was wrong because talent was the namespace in the route and not a nested resource.

I fixed the problem changing the helper to:

`talent/profile/header_helper.rb`

```
module Talent::Profile
  module HeaderHelper
    def display_experience(talent)
      talent.years_of_experience.present?  ? "#{talent.years_of_experience} #{t('.experience_years')}" : default_message
    end

    def default_message
      "No especificado"
    end
  end
end
```

fixed the problem.